# ADF Declarative component not being processed?

Tags: components, oracle-adf, declarative

So as the title says, I made a declarative component but when I add it to a web page it just displays the tag, and not the content

My tag

```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
      xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
 <af:componentDef var="attrs" componentVar="component">
 <af:goImageLink id="cm" icon="/img/contextmenu.gif" destination=""
                rendered="#{attrs.showPopup}">
  <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="contextMenu" triggerType="click"
                        alignId="cm" align="endAfter"/>
</af:goImageLink>
<af:popup id="contextMenu" contentDelivery="immediate" launcherVar="source"
          eventContext="self" rendered="#{attrs.showPopup}">
  <af:menu binding="#{backingBeanScope.popupProcedimentos.menu}" id="m1"></af:menu>
</af:popup>
<af:popup rendered="#{attrs.showPopup}" id="p1" contentDelivery="immediate"
          binding="#{backingBeanScope.popupProcedimentos.popupProcedimento}"
          launcherVar="source" eventContext="self">
  <af:dialog binding="#{backingBeanScope.popupProcedimentos.dialog}"
             stretchChildren="first" id="d1" title="Nova janela"
             contentWidth="500" contentHeight="500">
    <af:inlineFrame sizing="preferred"
                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.popupProcedimentos.inlineFrame}"
                    shortDesc="Nova página" id="iframe"
                    source="#{backingBeanScope.listaProcessoAdministrativo.procedimentoUrl}#{attrs.DDocName}"></af:inlineFrame>
  </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
<af:xmlContent>
  <component xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich/component">
    <display-name>popupProcedimentos</display-name>
    <component-extension>
      <component-tag-namespace>component</component-tag-namespace>
      <component-taglib-uri>/popupproceds</component-taglib-uri>
      <attribute>
        <attribute-name>showPopup</attribute-name>
        <attribute-class>java.lang.Boolean</attribute-class>
        <default-value>false</default-value>
      </attribute>
      <attribute>
        <attribute-name>DDocName</attribute-name>
        <required>true</required>
        <attribute-class>java.lang.String</attribute-class>
      </attribute>
    </component-extension>
  </component>
</af:xmlContent>
</af:componentDef>
</jsp:root>
```

And i just call it in the other page like this

```
>     <popupproced:popupProcedimentos DDocName="sss" id="popup"  showPopup="true" >  </popupproced:popupProcedimentos>
```

But the rendered html page just display the tag like that, any help?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the declarative component is invalid

***"> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"***

Frank

Comment: It was a copy and paste error actually, but I found out what was the problem, I forgot to declare the tag lib in the project of the page I was using to test it. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare the tag lib in the project of the page I was using to test it. Now everything is working fine.